# search results based on categories

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have the below spitting out by filter of Post Types but how could I use categories or custom fields?

```
 $categories = array(
        'post' => 'Articles',
        'mobile-experience' => 'Mobile',
        'staff-profiles' => 'Staff Profiles',
        'events' => 'Events',
        'page' => 'Page Content',);
```

I simply want to change wordpress search results page to populate under their categories.

*EG*. Search for keyword Cars.

**Category 1**

Cars (cars item found in this category)

**Category 2**

Cars (cars item found in this category)

**Category 3**

Nothing Found ( no cars item found in this category)

etc.

Searching by Keyword Cars.

Would grab anything with keywords Cars and populate under the category (items were found with keyword Cars under 2 Categories, and not 3; everywhere where found would populate)

Basically instead of shooting out all items with keyword Cars; it displays results under which category they search found keyword cars.

I just have 3 categories.

Recent attempt (trying 2 categories)

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
            <?php
                $s = get_search_query();
            ?>
    <div class="search">
        <div class="categoryThumbs">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <h3><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s'), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h3>
        <?php endif;?>
            <?php query_posts("s='$s'&category_name=build"); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php $blogResults=0; ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
                        $blogResults++;
                    ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <h4><?php echo $blogResults; ?> Results in BLOG</h4>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="films">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php query_posts("s='$s'&category_name=apps"); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php $blogResults=0; ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
                        $blogResults++;
                    ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <h4><?php echo $blogResults; ?> Results in Films</h4>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="films">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif;?>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you taking about `array_merge()` maybe? Do you have an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a hidden Field to your Search form using jquery,

each category have their own unique body class and you can use that class to only add different hidden field for different category,

You can use Jquery prepend or append,

```
(function($){ 

    //First Category
    $('.your-category-body-class .your-search-form-class').prepend('<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="category_name" value="your-category-slug" />');

    //Second Category

    $('.your-second-cat-body-class .your-search-form-class').prepend('<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="category_name" value="your-second-cat-slug" />')

})(jQuery)
```

The default wordpress form would look like this

```
<form method="get" class="search-form" action="http://your-site.com/" role="search">
    <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search Movie...">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

You can also do url query like this  `http://your-site.com/?post_type=your-custom-post&category_name=your-category-slug&post_tag=your-tag`

When when you do a search, it will return the url like this `http://your-site.com/?s=Your+Search+Phrase`

and your goal is to add predefined additional parameter in your search result to return something like `http://your-site.com/?s=Your+Search+Phrase&category_name=category-slug`

So you need your search form to be something like this

```
<form method="get" class="search-form" action="http://your-site.com/" role="search">
    <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search Movie...">
    <input type="hidden" id="foo" name="category_name" value="your-category-slug" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

And you can achieve that by the jquery I have provided above, you just need to get the correct selector

Or simply create your own search form

```
function my_custom_search_form() {
    echo '<form method="get" class="search-form" action="http://your-site.com/" role="search">'."\n";
    echo '<input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search Movie...">'."\n";
    if( is_category('your-category-slug-or-id') ) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="category_name" value="your-category-slug" />'."\n";
    } elseif(is_category('your-second-slug-or-id')) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="category_name" value="your-second-slug-or-id" />'."\n";
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Search">'."\n";
    echo '</form>';
}
```

then simply use `my_custom_search_form()` instead of wordpress default search form

**EDIT**

You can customize the search query parameter by adding hidden input fields on your form,

if you want to search the whole database, then thats the default wordpress search box,
returning url like this `http://your-site.com/?s=Your+Search+Phrase`

if you want to search within certain category then you need your search form to return the URL like this `http://your-site.com/?s=Your+Search+Phrase&category_name=your-category-slug`

if you want to search within two category, then you need your search form to return the url liek this `http://your-site.com/?s=Your+Search+Phrase&cat=1,2` where **1** and **2** is your category ID, or combine category slug `http://your-site.com/?s=Your+Search+Phrase&category_name=your-first-category-slug,second-category-slug`

You just need to add hidden value on your search form to add parameters that suits your need

Comment: But this wouldn't show both or all categories with the keywords in it?

Comment: Thanks but how can I print these search results in 3 different areas?! Eg. This is area #1: http://your-site.com/?s=Your+Search+Phrase&cat=1,2

Answer (score 0):

If you have another array, let's say $categories2, you can just do:

$result = array_merge($categories, $categories2);

Comment: I've answered based on my understanding of the question before you edited, but I don't understand your edit, can you please explain?

Comment: I have a wordpress website --- with categories, seeking to adjust search results page to allow the results to populate within their categories. I don't want to change the search function, but just allow the results to be grouped under category in the results page.

Comment: OK, got that, can you give an example please, the one in your question isn't particularly clear.

Comment: Does it make sense now? I just want to group results within categories